# What can be a limit of maximum number of external user in sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

I am having a Office365 subscription and according to my needs i want to share my sites with an external users. But my confusion is that up to how many external user i can share my SharePoint online sites,i searched on the web but not able to get any figure there, if any one had gone through such situation then please provide the suggestions or web link so that i can plan my external users for my Office365 site.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is completely based on the plan of your Office 365 Account.

You can only send invites up to 10,000 external users (meaning user's that is outside your organization or user's not licensed within the organization) per month If you are using Office 365 Enterprise plan.

This does not limit the access to the site collection but it pertains to the number of external user you can send an invitation to access the site.

You can find the appropriate answer according to your Office 365 plan from below location

[SharePoint Online and OneDrive for Business software boundaries and limits](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SharePoint-Online-and-OneDrive-for-Business-software-boundaries-and-limits-8f34ff47-b749-408b-abc0-b605e1f6d498?CorrelationId=6748da3e-fc70-431a-8814-59be40be500b&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

As it is frequently changing so you will get better idea from here [SEE VIDEO](https://mva.microsoft.com/en-us/training-courses/configure-external-user-sharing-using-sharepoint-online-10628?l=vE4ABHh8_6800115881)

Comment: I'll also add that Microsoft throttles you to 200 external user invitations per day.  I'm assuming that is per user.  A3 license.